# Manually Access Android Back Stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having problems coming up with a solution to this problem.

Basically I have a load of tabs in my ActionBar. When each is touched the fragments from the previous tab are detached and the fragments for the new tab are added using replace (if they haven't been instantiated yet) or attached (if they have). I think I got this method from Google and it was working fine until now.

Example of adding a tab's fragments:

```
if(tab.getText().equals(context.getString(R.string.title_class_tab))) {         
        if(browser == null) {
            browser = CourseBrowserFragment.newInstance(false);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(leftContainerId, browser);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.attach(browser);
        }

        if(lessonViewer == null) {
            lessonViewer = LessonViewerFragment.newInstance(false);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(rightContainerId, lessonViewer);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.attach(lessonViewer);
        }
}
```

and removing:

```
if(tab.getText().equals(context.getString(R.string.title_class_tab))) {         
        if(browser != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.detach(browser);
        }
        if(lessonViewer != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.detach(lessonViewer);
        }
}
```

The problem arises from the layout I need for one of the tabs. Basically it's like the Gmail app. There are two fragments (let's say Panel A and Panel B) and when you push a button Panel A slides out, Panel B slides to Panel A's old position and a new, third one (Panel C) slides in from the right.

I had this working fine but now I've added the sliding-in FragmentTransaction to the back stack so that the user can touch the back button and Panel C will slide back out and Panel A will come back. Again, like Gmail.

Except when the user goes to a different tab this transaction is still on the back stack and executes if the user presses back. The fragments end up in crazy places. What I need to do is remove it from the back stack when the user navigates to a different tab. Is there any way I can do this? FragmentManager doesn't seem to let you manually remove things from the back stack and using the popBackStack() method doesn't just remove the transaction, it executes it. I want to remove it when the user navigates away and put it back when the user returns.

I think I can get a hold of the "Back Stack Entry" for this transaction using "getBackStackEntryAt" but it's not much good if I can't remove it and put it back in place when the user comes back to the tab.

The only possible solution I can think of is not using the back stack and overriding onBackButtonPressed instead. From there I could just do a reverse of the transaction if necessary.

Thanks for any help and sorry if I'm being incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would qualify as a solution but I ended up just not adding the transaction to the back stack and just doing a fresh transaction when the user swiped or pressed back. The transaction just did the reverse of the original one with animations etc.

The way I managed the back button is I set a boolean to true if I was in the layout showing Panel C. If the user swipes back into the Panel A layout or navigates away the boolean is set to false. I then overrode the onBackButtonPressed method in the Activity and if the boolean was true (ie: we're in the Panel C layout) I run that reverse transaction otherwise I just call super.onBackButtonPressed() (ie: perform standard back button behaviour).